# Save screenshot of particles over a UI element

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to save a screenshot of particles over the top of a UI element in Unity 2017?

My Unity app involves showing particles over a video stream (from the device's camera). The video stream is a UI element that scales as the device's dimensions change.

My game view successfully shows the particles sitting over the top of the video UI canvas.

I’ve got that working by having a main camera with two child cameras: a GUI camera and a Particles camera. I’ve set the Clear Flags property for all three cameras to Depth Only, and the culling mask for each camera to UI+Particles, UI, and Particles respectively.

The problem I’m having is that the camera preview for my main camera looks like the attached – only particles (even though everything shows up on the game view).

[image: Main Camera view]

This is a problem because my screenshots and recordings use what’s on the main camera preview, and right now they’re only saving the particles, not the video behind them.

How can I make the main camera preview show both the UI and the Particles so it matches the game view? Or, is there a better way to get everything working?

The code for capturing a screenshot is on a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/david-arcus/0cc583c0d9f8666c5f84afd61bb648bd) - it does a great job of capturing what's on any camera - my problem is that I can only see particles on the camera I'm capturing

Comment: Add your screenshot code

Comment: I suspect it is related to your GUI camera. The scene view will render all cameras render combining together. But you are taking screenshot using just main camera where it renders only view from main camera. Are you using canvas as "Render Mode : Screen Space - Camera" & setting "Render camera" as your "GUI Camera"?? If so can you switch the "Render camera" as your maincamera and try it?It should give you the result but i suspect your other settings might change. Another solution is setting the canvas to world camera. This will render all the things above in main camera.

Comment: Play with these values I think this should be able to solve your problem.

Comment: @killer_mech I have two canvases, the GUI video canvas and the Particles canvas. Both have their Render Mode set to 'Screen Space - Camera', and their render cameras are set to the GUI camera and Particles respectively

Comment: @killer_mech If I set the render camera for the GUI canvas to the Main Camera, the UI shows in the Main Camera but the particles are no longer visible

Comment: @Programmer I've added a gist

Comment: @dave Ah my bad, i forgot that when you set render camera to a particular canvas it will only be rendered by that camera only assigned and no other camera but strangely enough your particle canvas is rendered by main camera. Is your particle canvas made of Unityparticle system? or just texture animation? If they it is texture animation done in UIcanvas then it should not render.One Solution is to bring the canvas and particles to world space. Have you tried moving them to world space? They should rendered by main camera. Is there any issue if you move both the canvases to world space?

Comment: @killer_mech Thanks for your help - I needed to avoid a World Space Camera in this case

Comment: Ah i see you forced all rendering in single camera ie main camera by using render texture instead of using world space.Im glad suggesstion helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by reverting my setup to the following:

I added two cameras - a Main Camera and a Particles Camera.

All my UI elements have their render mode set to Screen Space - Camera. My Particles camera is completely separate from my Main Camera. I created a new Render Texture, placed my particles in front of the Particles Camera, and set the Particle Camera's Target Texture to the Render Texture I'd just created.

Finally, I added a new Raw Image UI element to my UI Canvas, and set its texture to the Render Texture I'd created.

This not only displays the Particles in front of my UI elements but makes them visible in my Main Camera preview, so I can save screenshots of the camera.